# Why can't gcc vectorize this straight-line code?

Tags: c, gcc, vectorization

I have the following code, which seems like a perfect candidate for SLP:

```
struct vector {
  double x, y, z;
} __attribute__((aligned(16)));

int
slp_test(struct vector *x0, struct vector *n)
{
  double t = -x0->z/n->z;
  double u = x0->x + t*n->x;
  double v = x0->y + t*n->y;
  return t >= 0.0 && u >= 0.0 && v >= 0.0 && u + v <= 1.0;
}
```

The computations of `u` and `v` seem easily vectorizable, and `x0` and `n` ought to be aligned well enough for it.  But on x86-64 at `-O3`, gcc 4.9.0 generates this code:

```
    movsd   .LC0(%rip), %xmm1
    movsd   16(%rdi), %xmm0
    movsd   (%rdi), %xmm2
    xorpd   %xmm1, %xmm0
    movsd   (%rsi), %xmm1
    pxor    %xmm3, %xmm3
    divsd   16(%rsi), %xmm0 ; t = x0->z/n->z
    mulsd   %xmm0, %xmm1    ; t*n->x
    addsd   %xmm1, %xmm2    ; u = x0->x + t*n->x
    movsd   8(%rsi), %xmm1
    mulsd   %xmm0, %xmm1    ; t*n->y
    ucomisd %xmm3, %xmm2
    addsd   8(%rdi), %xmm1  ; v = x0->y + t*n->y
    setae   %dl
    ucomisd %xmm3, %xmm1
    setae   %al
    testb   %al, %dl
    je      .L3
    ucomisd %xmm3, %xmm0
    jb      .L3
    addsd   %xmm2, %xmm1
    movsd   .LC2(%rip), %xmm0
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    ucomisd %xmm1, %xmm0
    setae   %al
    ret
.L3:
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    ret
```

How come gcc doesn't use `mulpd` `addpd` instead of the two `mulsd`s and `addsd`s?  I used `-fopt-info-all-vec` to try to see why, and it complains about alignment ([full output](https://gist.github.com/tavianator/65f8642a5b859d6cb181)):

```
slp-test.c:8:17: note: === vect_analyze_data_refs_alignment ===
slp-test.c:8:17: note: vect_compute_data_ref_alignment:
slp-test.c:8:17: note: misalign = 0 bytes of ref x0_3(D)->z
slp-test.c:8:17: note: vect_compute_data_ref_alignment:
slp-test.c:8:17: note: misalign = 0 bytes of ref n_6(D)->z
slp-test.c:8:17: note: vect_compute_data_ref_alignment:
slp-test.c:8:17: note: misalign = 0 bytes of ref x0_3(D)->x
slp-test.c:8:17: note: vect_compute_data_ref_alignment:
slp-test.c:8:17: note: misalign = 0 bytes of ref n_6(D)->x
slp-test.c:8:17: note: vect_compute_data_ref_alignment:
slp-test.c:8:17: note: misalign = 8 bytes of ref x0_3(D)->y
slp-test.c:8:17: note: vect_compute_data_ref_alignment:
slp-test.c:8:17: note: misalign = 8 bytes of ref n_6(D)->y
slp-test.c:8:17: note: === vect_analyze_slp ===
slp-test.c:8:17: note: Failed to SLP the basic block.
slp-test.c:8:17: note: not vectorized: failed to find SLP opportunities in basic block.
```

Unless I've misinterpreted `__attribute__((aligned(16)))`, it should be able to force alignment for those accesses.  Any ideas?

Comment: Hm... I get `test.c:1:16: warning: attribute 'aligned' is ignored, place it after "struct" to apply attribute to type declaration [-Wignored-attributes]`.

Comment: Is that a clang warning?  My gcc doesn't seem to support it.  Anyway moving the `__attribute__((aligned(16)))` to the right place doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: There is no benefit vectorizing it. `u` and `v` need to be accessed individually after that. The overhead of the unpacking needed to do this outweighs the benefit of vectorizing a single arithmetic operation.

Comment: wel... I am not that knowledgeable in vectorization, but you do work with just one scalar pair. There is no loop for more scalars to be packed

Comment: @Mysticial The `u >= 0.0 && v >= 0.0` comparison should be vectorizable too, so unpacking is only needed for the `u + v <= 1.0` comparison which isn't always executed.

Comment: To vectorize `u >= 0.0 && v >= 0.0`, you need to do a packed compare. And then a packed test for zero. That isn't any better than two scalar comparisons.

Comment: @Mysticial It's "better" in the sense that it allows you to save a multiplication.  You're right that it may not be faster in practice though, I'll try to benchmark it.

Comment: For the record, a hand-written implementation with `mulpd`, `addpd`, and `cmppd` is 25% faster (12 vs 16 cycles) on my machine

Comment: @Mysticial: That seems to be beside the point if you play with the program a little.

Comment: @tmyklebu Then I suppose this is why they gave us intrinsics. You use them when you think you can do better than the compiler. And in this case, the OP has beaten the compiler.

Comment: @Mysticial Yay!  What do I win?

Comment: @TavianBarnes Ding ding ding!!! You have unlocked the, "Beat the Compiler" achievement!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this code will not profit from vectorization much, keep in mind that cpus are able to execute multiple instructions in a single cycle.
E.g on a Nehalem multiplication/addition has a latency of 4 and a reciprocal throughput of 1, so it should be able to compute 4 of these instructions in four cycles in the ideal case. Here at least 2 should be possible.
This already means you would gain nothing by using packed instruction even if the vector registers were already filed perfectly.

EDIT: I did not realize the data can be loaded in one move, so the setup cost might be negligible

In order to fill them you probably already need a high and low mov instruction which will cost you more than the few packed instruction will gain you later. (On Nehalem mov[hl]pd have a latency of ~5 while movsd has a latency of 2)

the comparison cannot be vectorized profitably either as you would need to unpack the packed comparison back into a normal register which is a very expensive operation.
Also the compiler does not know the probabilities of the branches, it must assume the first comparison will always short circuit the rest so doing anything in parallel will be harmful.

EDIT: with sse4 ptest it could be profitable though

The bottleneck here is also likely going to be the unvectorizable division.
You are probably better of trying to vectorize the operations of 2 structures at once instead of trying to vectorize the operations in one structure.

Comment: If you horse around a fair bit more doing vectorisable arithmetic, it still doesn't vectorise it.  (Say vector-mul by t, then vector-add x0->(x,y), thne vector-mul by t, then vector-add n->(x,y).)  Clang does vectorise it.

Comment: See my latest comment, vectorization does help performance here.  They can be filled with `movapd`, and the comparison can be done with `cmppd` `ptest` or similar.  Of course it's reasonable that gcc doesn't realise this.

Comment: interesting, I did overlook you can do one load and forgot about ptest, so it probably can save you cycles. I am a bit surprised that you can save 25%. fwiw ICC will also not vectorize it and clang will not use ptest even if allowed to use sse4

Comment: After some more careful benchmarking it seems that I was wrong; every version of the code (GCC's, Clang's, an explicitly vectorized one, and my hand-rolled vectorized assembly) take exactly 13 cycles for the `true` case, and around 9 cycles for the `false` case.  Additionally, gcc's version is significantly faster than all others if `true` and `false` cases are mixed.